# How can I center tab labels in `mat-tab-group` (Angular-Material)?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have this `mat-tab-group` which only has two tabs. The `mat-tab-group` container element width is bigger than the combined width of the two tab labels and I want to center the labels or increase the width in order to make them look cleaner. Thx in advance.

```
        <mat-tab-group>
            <mat-tab label="Person">
                <ng-template matTabContent>
                    <person-register></person-register>    
                </ng-template>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Company">
                <ng-template matTabContent>
                    <company-register></company-register>
                </ng-template>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: couldn't you show some codesamples?

Comment: The `mat-stretch-tabs` that suggested Marshal works fine! But I edited the answer anyway.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you add mat-stretch-tabs that should stretch the tabs across the width of your container and center the tab label.

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs></mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 13):

```html
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="center"></mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: while the accepted answer is a good answer, this is the correct answer